# Как создать такой круг?

Tags: css

Подскажите, как сделать такой круг с помощью css, как на рисунке?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

т.е. круг, состоящий из точек

Comment: Вам уже давали ответ, который вы приняли. Там участник с ником `Cheg` сделал вам такой круг средствами `css`

Answer (score 2):

Можно так:

```css
.circle{
  border: 3px dotted red;
  border-radius:50%;
  width: 200px;
  height:200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="circle"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
.circle {
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
border: 2px dotted red;
border-radius: 50%
}
```

```html
<div class="circle"></div>
```